# flex using curly braces in XML attributes value

Tags: apache-flex, escaping, curly-braces

I would like to set up a DataGrid with hard coded XML dataProvider.
One of my attributes value needs to be set to "{*}" which I know is interferring with data binding.
Hence, I tried to replace curly braces with their HTML equivalent but Flex is still processing `{*}` as data

```
<s:ArrayList>
  <fx:Object dataField1="Field1" dataField2="Field2" dataField3="&#123;*&#125;"></fx:Object>
</s:ArrayList>
```

**What is the proper way** to use curly braces in attributes text?

Comment: Escape with a backslash, I'd think.

Comment: Please quantify "Flex won't let me".  Do you get a compiler error?  Or a runtime error?

Comment: It basically treats  `&#123;` as `{` interpreting included value as a variable/constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use way mentioned by RIAstar:

`<fx:Object id="abc1" field1="\{*\}"/>`\

Or you can use real binding to make it treat anything inside it as a code, and then pass simple string without escaping `{` and `}` inside it:

`<fx:Object id="abc" field1="{'{*}'}"/>`

You can also use binding to a function that returns something if you need to set field to something more complex.

Comment: My bad for not trusting ActionScript with '\'

Comment: @MonoThreaded Don't you trust it _too_ much now: I don't think you can do `text="hello\"there\""` on an attribute for instance.